# Allow HTML Input in ASP.NET Databound Formview

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP:Formview that is databound to a LINQDatasource and one of my fields needs to have HTML allowable in it. (Its stored in a database and used to dynamically show formatted text on another webpage and this is how my customer will edit it)

The strange behavior is since it is databound, updating the data is peachy and has no problems with HTML tags. But when I use the formview Cancel button it throws up the "Dangerous text" error complaining about the tags. I've read and read about this and see the usual answers of "turn off pagevalidation" and "use Javascript to encode your text" But these don't work for me because;

Adding the requestValidaitonMode="2.0" to my web config and Pagevalidation=false to my page attribute don't fix the problem and I can't use javascript because its databound to the LINQdatasource so it does all its submission work inside that black box.

What options do I have here?

CODE:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="BoardDetails_LDS" runat="server" ContextTypeName="Boards_and_Commisions_Application.BoardsandCommissionsLINQDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="M_BoardsandCommissions" Where="BoardCommissionKey == @BoardCommissionKey" EnableDelete="True" EnableUpdate="True" EnableInsert="True">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="BoardCommissionKey" QueryStringField="B" Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>


     <asp:FormView ID="BoardDetails" runat="server" DataKeyNames="BoardCommissionKey" DataSourceID="BoardDetails_LDS" Style="float: left; width: 60%" DefaultMode="Edit">
  <EditItemTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">BoardCommissionKey:</span>
                        <asp:Label ID="BoardCommissionKeyLabel1" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BoardCommissionKey") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Board or Commission Name:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Board_or_Commission_NameTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Board_or_Commission_Name") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <%--                            <li>
                <span style="float: left">ApplicationXML:</span>
            <asp:TextBox ID="ApplicationXMLTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ApplicationXML") %>' />
                            </li>
                            <br />
                            <br />--%>
<%--                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Description:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox"  Style="float: right" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Description")%>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />--%>
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Default Contact Name:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Default_Contact_NameTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Default_Contact_Name") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Default Email:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Default_EmailTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Default_Email") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Default Phone:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Default_PhoneTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Default_Phone") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Default Web:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Default_WebTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Default_Web") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Appointment Type:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Appointment_TypeTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Appointment_Type") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Authority:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AuthorityTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Authority") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Term Length:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TermLengthTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TermLength") %>' />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TermLengthTextBoxRequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TermLengthTextBox" Style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; color: Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must Enter Value"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Special Requirements:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Special_RequirementsTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Special_Requirements") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <span style="float: left">Staff Contact:</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Staff_ContactTextBox" Style="float: right" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Staff_Contact") %>' />
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <li>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" Style="float: right" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" PostBackUrl="~/InternalSite/MenuTypem.aspx" Style="float: left" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                        &nbsp<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" PostBackUrl="~/InternalSite/MenuTypem.aspx" Style="float: left; margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%; align-self: center" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
```

Comment: You need to work with HTML Encode/Decode functions. As you didn't post how your code looks like, i can't give you a direct answer, but i hope this helps: 
In server side you can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string); 
In client-side you can use the jQuery functions .html() and .text().

Comment: Durp, I knew I forgot something. Ok I've pasted in the entirety of my relavant code. I'm currently relying completely on the functionality provided by the LINQDataSource and the Formview so there's no other Codebehind or Javascript involved currently.